# Nginx redirects instead of doing reverse proxy with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have an nginx running on a docker container, which serves a web client.

I want to proxy requests from the client, so that the nginx will pass the POST requests to the server, since the actual destination endpoint is not accessible to the client.

This is the location directive:

```
location /zipkin {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host    $host:$server_port;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server  $host;
  proxy_set_header Host                $host;
  proxy_pass http://my-ip:9411/;
}
```

The client makes requests to `http://localhost:8080/zipkin/api/v2/span`, which I want the nginx to pass (without redirection) to `http://my-ip:9411/api/v2/span`.

What happens in practice is that I get a `301` response (to `http://localhost:8080/api/v2/span`), and the POST is never sent to the destination.

Edit: another try that returns 404 -

```
location /zipkin/ {
  rewrite ^/zipkin/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://my-ip:9411$uri; # tried 9411;, 9411/, 9411$uri, 9411$uri/
}
```

Here `$uri` is `/api/v2/span`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the end was:

```
location ~ ^/zipkin(/?)(.*) {
  proxy_pass http://my-ip:9411/$2;
}
```

One of my tries was `^/zipkin(.*)` but it evidently didn't work.

Probably the `/` after the `/zipkin` is problematic, so `(/?)` removes it,
And that leaves the `(.*)` the clean part of the url which needs to be attached to the `proxy_pass`ed url.